# p:selectOneMenu dropdown not attached to the component inside a dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

I have a p:selectOneMenu inside a p:dialog. Whenever I scroll the page, the dropdown detaches from the p:selectOneMenu label and moves according to the mouse scroll. Is there any way to attach it to the label so that it doesn't move?

Here's a screenshot of the problem posted by someone who has the same problem [SelectOneMenu panel scrolls with the mouse wheel](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=14905)

Comment: In that post you wrote that you are using version 3.0 M3. Is that true? If it is, you should move to some newer version, at least some release. An also if this doesn't help please post relevant code so we can reproduce this.

Comment: That is someone else's post. I just happen to have to the same problem. I am using Primefaces 3.5

Answer (score 6):

In case someone finds this question, I want to add here that this problem can be found in newer versions of Primefaces (5.0+) and you can solve it by using `appendTo="@this"` in the `p:selectOneMenu`. I just found it and solved it in another more recent question.

**Related:**

[SelectOneMenu scrolls with the mouse wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26288576/4056222)