# Floating p:calendar when scrolling

Tags: java, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces 5.0.5 with GlassFish server 3.1.2.2.

I added `<p:calendar>` inside a `<ui:fragment>` which is then included in another XHTML page.

When I open the select menu and scroll with the mouse wheel, the panel will float with the page.

I've already checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26228872/pselectonemenu-dropdown-part-scrolls-and-does-not-stay-in-position) with a similar issue but not on the same component.

The same trick doesnt work for calendar. I've tried appending it to components around but none of them works.

Any feedback and comment are appreciated.

Many thanks.

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2"  id="..." style="margin: 0px 0px 30px 15px;">
    <h:outputText value="#{msg['startDate']}:"/>
        <p:calendar
            pattern="dd-MM-yyyy"
            converterMessage="#{msg['ocs.invalidStartDateFormat']}"
            value="#{cc.attrs.inputObject.usageHistoryStartDate}"
            disabled="#{cc.attrs.inputObject.usageHistoryBillingPeriodOption != 'CUSTOM_DATE_RANGE'}"
            showOn="button">
        </p:calendar>
    <h:outputText value="#{msg['endDate']}:" />
        <p:calendar
            pattern="dd-MM-yyyy"
            converterMessage="#{msg['invalidEndDateFormat']}"
            value="#{...}"
            disabled="#{...}"
            showOn="button">
        </p:calendar>
</h:panelGrid>
```

[image: Issue screenshot]

Comment: I also have same issue. Still don't have solution?

Comment: Nope.. will ask on es.stackoverflow there's currently a reward program for bounty so I hope I can get something there :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would help you, but my workaround is to add a scroll event on the dialog or whatever container component you have. In the scroll event, you look for the datepicker element and hide it. Here is a snippet:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
            var dialog1 = $('.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content');

            dialog1.scroll(function() {
                $('#ui-datepicker-div').hide();
            });
        });
```