# primefaces autocomplete suggestion panel opening away from input field

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, autocomplete, materialize

I'm using primefaces autocomplete in a .xhtml page that uses Materialize CSS style. My .xhtml pages use JSF 2.2. Sometimes when I start typing, the suggestion panel appears far away from the input field, and sometimes don't. What can be happening?

[Panel appearing away from the input field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdpZ8.png)

[Panel appearing correctly, near the input field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ll8Nn.png)

I created my custom autocomplete component using JSF composite, here's the code

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
/**
 * Função usada para disparar a seleção de um elemento, após o clique na lista de sugestão
 */
function selectSuggestion(){
 id = arguments[0];
 if(document.getElementById('formSearch:'+id+':'+id+'_input').value!=null &amp;&amp; document.getElementById('formSearch:'+id+':'+id+'_input').value!=''){
  top.setSelecaoPesquisaJsMB([{name:'openDialog',value:arguments[1]}]);
 } 
}
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
 xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets" 
 xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
 xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core" 
 xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" 
 xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

<composite:interface>
 <composite:attribute name="id" default="buscaInput" shortDescription="ID do autoComplete. Usado para referencia em outras partes do código" />
 <composite:attribute name="value" shortDescription="Elemento selecionado" />
 <composite:attribute name="style" shortDescription="Estilo complementar" />
 <composite:attribute name="styleClass" />
 <composite:attribute name="size" default="35" />
 <composite:attribute name="placeholder" />
 <composite:attribute name="completeMethod" />
 <composite:attribute name="scrollHeight" default="500" />
 <composite:attribute name="openDialog" default="#{true}"/>
 <composite:attribute name="onkeypress"/>
 <composite:attribute name="rendered" default="#{true}"></composite:attribute>
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>

 <p:autoComplete id="#{cc.attrs.id}" style="#{cc.attrs.style}" styleClass="#{cc.attrs.styleClass}" placeholder="#{cc.attrs.placeholder}" size="#{cc.attrs.size}"
  effect="fade" forceSelection="true" minQueryLength="3" scrollHeight="#{cc.attrs.scrollHeight}" onkeypress="#{cc.attrs.onkeypress}"
  panelStyle="width: 247px !important; overflow: auto; background-color: white !important;" maxResults="50"
  emptyMessage="#{message['message.search.naoEncontrado']}" value="#{cc.attrs.value}" completeMethod="#{searchMB.autoCompletar}" var="item"
  itemLabel="#{item.nome}" itemValue="#{item}" converter="elementoLocalizavelConverter">
  <p:ajax event="itemSelect" oncomplete="selectSuggestion('#{cc.attrs.id}','#{cc.attrs.openDialog}')" immediate="true" listener="#{mapaMB.handleSelect}" />
  <p:column style="width:10%">
   <img src="${facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/images/#{searchMB.stripDiacriticsTrimLowercase(item.entidade)}.png" />
  </p:column>
  <p:column>
   <h:outputText value="#{item.nome}" />
  </p:column>
 </p:autoComplete>

</composite:implementation>
</html>
```

Here's is the code that calls my autoCompletion component.

```
<div class="col s6">
        <h:outputLabel value="#{message['label.rota.pontaB']}* for="buscaInput2" />
        <sicaf:autoCompletion id="buscaInput2" openDialog="false" size="25" onkeypress="return disableEnterKey(event)" value="#{melhorRotaMB.pontaB}" />
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [p:selectOneMenu dropdown part scrolls and does not stay in position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26228872/pselectonemenu-dropdown-part-scrolls-and-does-not-stay-in-position)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I've found the solution! I don't know if it's the best one but here it is.

I've put ***position: fixed*** on primefaces autocomplete ***panelStyle*** attribute and the problem was solved.

I inspected with Chrome's F12 and realized the panel was ***position: relative***. I think this config confused the autocomplete component about relative to who, causing the misfunction.

Well, I spent some hours looking for it, and 10 minutes later of posting it here, I've found a solution. That's wierd. Whatever, thanks!