# scroll- or overflow-problem with p:selectOneMenu inside dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using Primefaces  6.2. When placing a selectbox inside a dialog and open it, it will scroll along the main page.

To avoid that, i've added `appendTo="@(this)"`. With this change the scrolling works correctly, but if the height of the dropdown overflows the dialog height, automatically scrollbards are created for the dropdown and the dialog.

Example:

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="eventDialog" >
   <p:selectOneMenu id="dummy" value="Selection" appendTo="@(this)">
      <f:selectItems value="selection 1" />
      <f:selectItems value="selection 2" />
   </p:selectOneMenu>
</p>
```

To avoid the scrollbars and let the dropdown overflow i've tried `panelStyle="position:fixed"` instead of `appendTo="@(this)"`. With this solution i have the problem, that the dropdown is not visible if i have a big page and scrolld down to the bottom, open the dialog and click on the dropdown.

Example:

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="eventDialog" >
   <p:selectOneMenu id="dummy" value="Selection" panelStyle="position:fixed">
      <f:selectItems value="selection 1" />
      <f:selectItems value="selection 2" />
   </p:selectOneMenu>
</p>
```

By the way i found the two solutions in the post "[p:selectOneMenu dropdown part scrolls and does not stay in position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26228872/pselectonemenu-dropdown-part-scrolls-and-does-not-stay-in-position)".

Comment: Try `appendTo="<selector for dialog content div>"` it might work

Comment: I just saw you ended up asking this question for a third problem with selects, but this one I cannot reproduce it. One thing... I'm guessing it's a typo from trying to hide production code, but your examples have some things wrong, like closing with just </p>, or having f:selectItems with just a string value.