# How to fix p:selectOneMenu result item lists moves as when mouse scrolls and not stick to selectOnMenu box

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

p:selectOneMenu result itemlists are initially shows stick to selectOneMenu dropdown, As when I scroll using mouse scroller the result Itemlist moves up or down as I scroll the mouse. 
This p:selectOneMenu I have in the dialog box.

This works fine if I use the h:selectOneMenu. The problem is in p:selectOneMenu (primeface 6.2 version).
I have tried with attribute PanelStyle="position:fixed;" but this not helped. The problem appears only in when I use mouse scroller.
Can somebody please guide me how to fix this.

```html
<p:dialog header="Add User" widgetVar="addUserWidget" id="addUserWidgetId" modal="true">
        <p:fragment>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="myGridPanelId" width="180px">
                <h:panelGroup id="groupPan">
                    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{myBean.selectedUser}" style="width:140px;">
                        <f:selectItems
                            value="#{myBean.userLists}" id="userNameItem" 
                            var="user" itemLabel="#{user.name}" itemValue="#{user.name}">
                        </f:selectItems>
                        <f:ajax event="change" execute="@this" render="groupPan" listener="#{myBean.userAdd()}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:panelGrid id="panelBtnGrid">
                    <p:commandButton ajax="true" value="Add" id="addBtnId" process="@this"
                        action="#{myBean.saveUser()}" />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:fragment>
    </p:dialog>
```

The result Item list should stick to the p:selectOneMenu dropdown box.

Comment: Tried appendTo? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26228872/pselectonemenu-dropdown-part-scrolls-and-does-not-stay-in-position#26288576 and tried a newer version?

Comment: Thanks Kukeltje.Tried with **appendTo="@this"** and **panelStyle="position: fixed;"** together and even the **appendTo="@this"** alone. This solves the original issue. But the other problem now is the dialog height is 200px and the result list quite big(around 20 results) so only the 5 results are shown and rest are hidden under the dialog. I want to see all the result list.                                          if i use mouse scroller it scrolls result list and shows rest of result list. but cannot see without mouse scroller. Can you please guide me how to fix this.

Comment: Play with  css overflow