# p:calendar popup remain below from calendar input in dialog when scroll (on IE and Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, primefaces, calendar, explorer

When scroll on page and open dialog with IE or Chrome, calendar popup remain below from calendar input. i called PF(widgetVar).alignPanel(); function on a lot of ajax events(onfocus, onselect ...)  but only onclick event works. but if user use tab (not with click event), it isnt work. on EI or Chrome, when i click calendar input, popup remain below but if i resize window, popup appears right position. (firefox works perfectly)

i use pf 7.0, tomcat 8.5, jsf 2.1

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<f:view contentType="text/html">
    <h:head></h:head>

    <h:body>
        <p:spacer height="2000" />
        <p:commandButton value="Open Dialog" type="button" onclick="PF('dlg').show();" />

        <p:dialog widgetVar="dlg">
            <p:calendar />
        </p:dialog>

    </h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

i hope it is ok.

[image]

Comment: Can you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26228872/pselectonemenu-dropdown-part-scrolls-and-does-not-stay-in-position?

Comment: primefaces dialogs default position value is "fixed" and my all dialogs appends to body.

Comment: There is way more in there then the dialog default position and it is not specifically related to the appendTo of the dialog but the select (so might apply to the calendar too)

Comment: i tried to set position "absolute" for dialog, calendar works correctly but this time dialog stay same position when i scroll on page.

Comment: read about changing things on the select (and try to do the same on the calendar) **that** is the main thing about the other questio... The appendTo part, like stated on the previous comment. Try to NOT focus that much on the dialog

Comment: i called PrimeFaces.widget.Calendar.prototype.alignPanel function on calendar beforeShow event but it didnt work. i override _showDatePicker event of jQuery but didnt work.

Comment: Since you have no [mcve], it is impossible to see why it does not work for you... So please create one... asap...

Comment: And did you try PF p:calendar as an alternative?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code there. Formatted and in [mcve] flavour.