# List of values (selectOneMenu) below PDF

Tags: primefaces, z-index, selectonemenu, object-tag

I'm using a p:selectOneMenu to render a list of values. When the user click in the p:selectOneMenu the list of values is being painted below a 'html object tag' that is used to show a PDF. In the image I've attached is possible to see what is my problem.

Here is the code:

```
   <p:layout style="width:100%; height:100%; min-height: 600px;" id="layoutShowScannedDocs" >
        <p:layoutUnit position="center" >                                   
            <p:outputPanel  id="opScannedDoc" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding:0px; z-index:20;"> 
              <object id="iframescanneddoc" type="application/pdf" width="100%" data="...url.." />
            </p:outputPanel>
        </p:layoutUnit>
        <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="60" >
            <div style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">
              <p:selectOneMenu id="listOfValues" widgetVar="listOfValues"  value="#{MyBean.selectedValue}" style="float:center;" >
                 <p:ajax event="change" />                                                                          
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msgs.field_estadoelaboracion_original}" itemValue="1" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msgs.field_estadoelaboracion_cambioformato}" itemValue="2" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msgs.field_estadoelaboracion_docpapel}" itemValue="3" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msgs.field_estadoelaboracion_parcial}" itemValue="4" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msgs.field_estadoelaboracion_otros}" itemValue="5" />                                        
            </p:selectOneMenu>          
           </div>
        </p:layoutUnit>
   </p:layout>
```

What could I do to see the list of values of the p:selectOneMenu over the 'html object tag'?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: maybe play with the z-index (css)..

Comment: I've tried it but it doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: make your question more general. It is all client-side. The object tag is one... Does it work with a non-primefaces selectone? if not it is plain html and object tag related. Tagging you question like that might get you better and quicker help

Comment: I'm sorry if it is not properly tagged. I've tried to be concise when describing my problem, because I thought it was better. Anyway, I'm going to update my question with more info.

Comment: You posted **server side** xhtml while the basic problem is the client-side html (as mentioned in my comment). Downvote from me now

Comment: I don't understand at all why downvote. You are right is a client-side problem but the selectOneMenu tag is not rendered as a normal html select, and I thought that perhaps someone who have had a similar problem using a primefaces selectOneMenu could help me. Anyway, I'm going to think how to rewrite and retag my question

Comment: I've resolved my problem using h:selectOneMenu instead of p:selectOneMenu. I know that this is a workaround and not a real solution, but this is better than nothing. I've seen another possible solution, but it not a straightforward solution so I will try it when I have free time. The solution is playing with z-index and placing a iframe between the object tag and the div with the list of values. Here it is possible to read the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593176/div-layer-on-top-of-pdf

Comment: Try adding an `appendTo="@this"` on the `p:selectOneMenu`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286454/pselectonemenu-dropdown-not-attached-to-the-component-inside-a-dialog

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried it some time ago but it doesn't work. Adding  an appendTo="@this" on the p:selectOneMenu place the div with the list of values in other place of the html, but is still below the object tag (Internet Explorer). So I'm afraid that the solution is what I suggested in my last comment.